# USB device powered down, probably by Window's selective suspend, when connected though a USB hub, but works when connected directly

Tags: laptop, power

I have a setup where a user have connected an older Mousetrapper device and a keyboard though the USB hub integrated in a desktop screen. However, after a few minutes the mousetrapper is shut down, ever while in use and does not awake regardless of any input action. However, when connected directly to the laptop instead of the USB hub, the issue disappears and it works perfectly. I would appreciate any suggestions of what could be the issue here.

The problem appeared when users were put on new laptops with Win 10, the devices had worked perfectly with older machines and Win 7.

I have attempted to disable selective suspend of the devices in the windows device manager and to disable selective USB suspend from power options. Mousetrapper support could not provide any leads.

As it works when plugged directly into the laptop, i have guessed it has to do with the power settings related to the USB hub, and that the "keep awake" signal might not be transmitted correctly over the USB hub. However, it does not appear to affect any other devices.

**Hardware setup**:

- Mousetrapper device: Mousetrapper Advance, 5-10 years old. Connected 
  to the screen USB hub with a standard USB cable. Runs on a generic
  HID driver (there's no official mousetrapper driver except "KT keys",
  which does not affect the issue)
- Keyboard: Generic, connected to the screen USB hub with a standard USB cable.
- Screen: Dell U3417W, USB hub connected to laptop with a superspeed (SS) USB    cable.
- OS: Win 10 1709
- Laptop: Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon, 6th gen